# Python find the unique values in a spesific column. 2d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, unique

Good day.

If I have the following array:

```
[11, "apples", 22, 11], [12, "pear", 24, 11], [13, "bannana", 18, 11], [14, "pear", 17, 11]
```

How can I change the array to only show data from user `pear`? I want to collect all the values from column 1 of user `pear`. (12, 14)

Or alrternatively how can I find the values that are unique in colum 2, e.g. apples, pear and bannana. And then filter by `pear` to find the data only of `pear`. *[12, "pear", 24, 11], [14, "pear", 17, 11]*

What have I tried and vary forms of it:

`uniqueRows = np.unique(array, axis=:,1)`

This is what I can use to filter if I have the unique values.

```
new_arr = np.array([[11, "apples", 22, 11], [12, "pear", 24, 11], [13, "bannana", 18, 11], [14, "pear", 17, 11]])
new_val = np.array(["pear"])
result = np.in1d(new_arr[:, 1], new_val)
z = new_arr[result]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas Way

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

new_arr = np.array([[11, "apples", 22, 11], [12, "pear", 24, 11], [13, "banana", 18, 11], [14, "pear", 17, 11]])

df = pd.DataFrame(new_arr,columns=['A','B','C','D'])

result = df[df.B=='pear']
print(result)
'''
    A     B   C   D
1  12  pear  24  11
3  14  pear  17  11
'''
#or

result_2 = df['B'].drop_duplicates()
print(result_2)
'''
0    apples
1      pear
2    banana
'''
```

However instead of drop_duplicate you can use unique() but this way is faster.

Comment: Thank you this gave me the first part that I wanted. Can I ask how can I then use `result_2`.  How can I use the value of 'pear' after it was filttered by panda and is now inside `result_2[1]`.

Comment: Your welcome. what you want to achieve with result_2.  You should be more specific. Give me more details.

Comment: Alright since I have each unique user now. Then I can use each user to filter the array to gather all the 'scores' of that user.(colum C) That is my end goal. To have a string that says `User pear has achieved the following marks; 24, 17.` And be able to do that for each user.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your question, it appears that using `numpy` isn't necessarily a requirement, so this is how you could do it using standard list comprehension. Feel free to select a different answer if `numpy` is a hard requirement

I'll assume the input is called `data`.

First we iterate through each item in our list and we could get each word key

```py
[item[1] for item in data]
```

This generates a list of the words (the second element of each subarray)

```py
['apples', 'pear', 'bannana', 'pear']
```

But we don't really want that array as our result, we want to **check** that array to get our result. So using the same `for..in` syntax, we can check each item as we iterate

```py
[item[1] for item in data if item[1] == 'pear']
```

Gets us

```py
['pear', 'pear']
```

So now we have filtered down to all `pear` sub-arrays. But we really want the first item (or possibly the whole object) so we can just change the index of what we're "selecting" at the beginning of our `for...in` list comprehension.

```py
[item[0] for item in data if item[1] == 'pear']
```

That will give us

```py
[12, 14]
```

If you do want the whole item, you can just choose not to index the result at all

```py
[item for item in data if item[1] == 'pear']
```

```py
[[12, 'pear', 24, 11], [14, 'pear', 17, 11]]
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer. But if I do not know the username is pear but rather 'x'. How would I use it then.

I will be importing data from sql and the users will constily change. So I need to find a way to filter by user.

Comment: You would just replace 'pear' in the formula with whatever your variable is. I can extract it to a variable quite simply

`x = 'pear'`

`[item for item in data if item[1] == x]`

Comment: If I can filter the array to get the unique values of column 2. Then I can go through each user and make them 'user' == x. And then ```[item[0] for item in data if item[1] == x']```

Answer (score 0):

1. *alrternatively how can I find the values that are unique in colum 2, e.g. apples, pear and bannana. And then filter by pear to find the data only of pear. [12, "pear", 24, 11], [14, "pear", 17, 11]*.

I believe for the above, you have already answered it yourself. Correct me if I interpreted it wrong.

2. *How can I change the array to only show data from user pear? I want to collect all the values from column 1 of user pear. (12, 14)*

If you want to collect only from 1st column, you can transpose the array created by your code, and return the first array.

```py
new_arr = np.array([[11, "apples", 22, 11], [12, "pear", 24, 11], [13, "bannana", 18, 11], [14, "pear", 17, 11]])
new_val = np.array(["pear"])
result = np.in1d(new_arr[:, 1], new_val)
z = new_arr[result]
```

The above is what you wrote, you can then do:

```py
print(z.T[0])

#If you want it in list, you can do
#print(list(z.T[0]))
```

Output:

> array(['12', '14'], dtype='<U21')

Comment: Yes my way of filter will work, where I run into a problem is that if the user is not pear - but rather x. I will be importing data from sql and the users will constily change. So I need to find a way to filter by user.

Comment: Can't you just do, `result = np.in1d(new_arr[:, 1], np.array(x))`, where x = <user>?

Comment: There will be a lot of records spread out. With each user have multiple entries. Therefore I need to filter by user so that for each user - I can gather the data individually and use that data to say `user x has done; 11, 13, 15` as an example.